# Creating a Model From a URL parameter in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create an instance of a class based on a parter that is passed in by the url. This is what I have so far. I found a question about this that was asked more than two. years ago using this same format, but I am getting an error.

```
public function completed($type,$id){
     $model = app("\App\{$type}");
}
```

The error I get is :

> Class \App{EmailMessage} does not exist

It seems like the string interpolation is not working correctly.

Comment: It should be `$model = app("\App\\${type}");`

Comment: Use double backslash

Comment: Is that just escaping the character?